# Sort NSArray with capital letters

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` that looks like this:

```
contactNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"John Galt", @"Michael Wales", @"James Joyce", @"Shakespeare", nil];
```

From it, I want to make an `NSArray` that would have *all the same values*, but that would look like this:

```
newContactNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"john galt", @"michael wales", @"james joyce", @"shakespeare", nil];
```

I want to do this because I want to make a search in that second array and I want to replace *every capital letter* in it with a normal letter.

How do you do something like this in Objective-C? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go through an array, and convert every element to lower case by calling

```
[element lowercaseString]
```

on it. However, this is grossly suboptimal for implementing case-insensitive search: a better approach would be keeping strings as-is, and employ `caseInsensitiveCompare` method for your search instead.

Comment: The second option is much better! I'll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Why are you making a copy? You can sort an NSArray in a case insensitive way:

```
NSArray *sortedContactNamesArray = [contactNamesArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Also, bear in mind that `sortedArrayUsingSelector` returns an array with references to the original items, not copies of them.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great way to do this!

Comment: Strangely enough, I get an NSArray with the same NSStrings as in an old array.

Comment: @SergiusGee Nothing strange about it. Sorting doesn't change the values. This approach states that case should be ignored when determining the sort order. But no values are actually changed.